# Divine Favor learned prayer for regenerating FP through meditation?

Tags: cleric, gurps-4e, divine

I really like the concept of Divine Favor learned prayers to use with clerics. It gives them a more unique set of powers and makes gameplay more diverse.

I have a cleric character that uses it and has DF at level 8 and has both Lay on Hands and Flesh Wounds documented in *Powers - Divine Favor*. 
This way he can grant heal to other people from his own HP pool and then cure himself.

I was looking into some FP regeneration ability. There is a Healing School spell called Recover Energy which accelerates the FP recovery from 1 per 10 minutes to 1 per minute at skill level 15 or more, no further increment is possible.

How could I build this learned prayer with the DF rules?

Comment: To clarify, "Recover Energy" recovers 1 per 5 minutes at skill 15, or 1 per 2 minute at 20 -- with no further increase possible.  One per minute is not possible with `Recover Energy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this. The simplest would be a variant of *Flesh Wounds*, called something like *Energy from Prayer*, which would use Fatigue regeneration instead of HP regeneration. That costs the same as HP regeneration, per p. 70 of ***GURPS Powers***.

***Energy from Prayer***

*Learned Prerequisite*: Divine Favor 5.

*Learned Prayer Cost*: 3 points.

If you pray for this miracle after becoming fatigued, your connection to your deity revitalises you. You recover 1 FP per minute of prayer, for up to ten minutes. You cannot invoke this more often than once every 15 minutes, whether used as a specific or learned prayer.

*Statistics*: Regeneration (FP, +0%; Fast; Divine, -10%; Requires Concentrate, -15%; Maximum Duration, 10 minutes, -50%) [13].

Comment: Shouldn't there be some cost modifier to account for the fact that such regeneration requires constant focus on praying, instead of being simply active during these 10 minutes after the second that a concentration maneuver takes? After all, this is a severe limitation for adventuring purposes.

Comment: @DeFazer: You're right, added.

Comment: And the Learned Prayer cost drops to 3, correct?

Comment: @gtludwig: Yes, exactly.